# Displaying pie chart in imagelist

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am developing a project in vb.net , i am making a pie chart using a image list but the problem is that the text box used to enter the data is in another image and the output should be displayed in another image. m getting a piechart if m doing it in a single form . plz help me with come code to fetch ths value.

Comment: What UI technology are you using? Is this a website or Windows app? If you could edit your question to include information about what you've tried so far then we might be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

its a windows application.i hv used imagelist instead of using tabs.the pie diagram should be displayed in the first image part and the values from which the pie is being displayed is in another image.

The code for pie diagram is here-Imports Charting = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting
Imports ComponentModel = System.ComponentModel
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    form2.show()
End Sub
Public Class Form3

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged

End Sub
```

End Class

Public Class Form1
    ' use a BindingList to signal list changes
    Private WithEvents Sectors As New ComponentModel.BindingList(Of SectorItem)

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ' setting text just for demo purposes
    'TextBox1.Text = "10"
    'TextBox2.Text = "5"

    ' define a piechart series
    Dim PieSeries1 As New Charting.Series("Pie1")
    PieSeries1.ChartType = Charting.SeriesChartType.Pie
    PieSeries1.CustomProperties = "PieLabelStyle=Disabled"

    Chart1.Series.Clear()                  ' reset the chart Series collection
    Chart1.Series.Insert(0, PieSeries1)    ' add PieSeries1 to Chart1

    ' add the SectorItems
    Sectors.Add(New SectorItem(TextBox1, "Sector 1"))
    Sectors.Add(New SectorItem(TextBox2, "Sector 2"))
    Sectors.Add(New SectorItem(TextBox3, "Sector 3"))
    Sectors.ResetItem(0) ' force a ItemChanged event to set the Points DataBinding
End Sub

''' <summary>
''' Updates the chart data each time any of the SectorItems changes due to a Name Change or the
''' databound TextBox.Text changes   
''' </summary>
Private Sub sectors_ListChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.ListChangedEventArgs) Handles Sectors.ListChanged
    If e.ListChangedType = ComponentModel.ListChangedType.ItemChanged Then
        Chart1.Series("Pie1").Points.DataBind(Sectors, "", "Value", "Label=Name")
    End If
End Sub

''' <summary>
''' a helper class for binding a TextBox value to a chart.  
''' </summary>
Private Class SectorItem
    ' implement INotifyPropertyChanged to signal changes to the property values
    Implements System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged
    Public Event PropertyChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs) Implements System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

    Public Sub New(ByVal tb As TextBox, ByVal Name As String)
        Me._Name = Name
        Double.TryParse(tb.Text, _Value)
        ' bind Value to the TextBox.Text Property
        ' You may want to use DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation instead of  DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged
        ' OnPropertyChanged fires on each change as you type in the TextBox
        tb.DataBindings.Add("Text", Me, "Value", True, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged)
    End Sub

    Private Sub NotifyPropertyChanged(ByVal info As String)
        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(info))
    End Sub

    Private _Name As String
    Public Property Name() As String
        Get
            Return _Name
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            ' only singal change if value actually changes
            Dim notify As Boolean = Not String.Equals(_Name, value)
            _Name = value
            If notify Then NotifyPropertyChanged("Name")
        End Set
    End Property 'Name

    Private _Value As Double
    Public Property Value() As Double
        Get
            Return _Value
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Double)
            ' only singal change if value actually changes
            Dim notify As Boolean = (_Value <> value)
            _Value = value
            If notify Then NotifyPropertyChanged("Value")
        End Set
    End Property 'Value
End Class ' SectorItem
```

End Class